# Create a Cabinet file in Java

Tags: java

does anyone know a library that makes it possible to create a cabinet file in pure Java?

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a java application to do this (pure java implementation). It does not support compression and so it basically just packages the files together and adds the cabinet header to the system. It isn't too complicated to do, took me about a day to bash it out.

Not too sure how complex it would be to implement compression but I assume it would not be all that trivial. There is a fair bit of information available on the net on the structure of the cabinet file format.

EDIT: now available on github: https://github.com/grahamrb/CabinetMaker

Comment: Graham, any chance you could share this app or your code to create cabs under some open source license?

Comment: For sure, apologies in advance, I wrote the code while at uni so it isn't fabulous but hopefully it helps you: https://github.com/grahamrb/CabinetMaker

Answer (score 1):

To get started you can use Java's DeflaterOutputStream to do Deflate compression which is one of the supported cab compression schemes.

Oh whaddaya know... I found one: [cablib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cablib) (but it's not in development since 2006)

Comment: jcablib, was also what i found, but the source forge site talks only about extracting files.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can only create .cab files using the [CABARC utility](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/310618) from Microsoft. So there is no "pure java" implementation.

You can call something like:

```
CABARC n myArchive.cab *.*
```

using [Runtime.getRuntime().exec()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) to create myArchive.cab.

Comment: sry, thats not a solution to the problem, because it is not really platform independent.

Comment: You should probably update your question to indicate that you need a platform independent solution. Also, given that .cab is a proprietary Microsoft format, I'm not sure that you'd be able to find a solution that work outside of Windows.